# Getting the base path/URL

Tags: php, url, base-path

I am trying to get the base path of the documents through a function as I do not want to find the paths like `../folder1/folder2/mypage.php` or `../../../folder1/folder2/somepage.php`.

Therefore I tried...

```
function getBaseUrl() {
// output: /myproject/index.php
$currentPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// output: Array ( [dirname] => /myproject [basename] => index.php [extension] => php [filename] => index )
$pathInfo = pathinfo($currentPath);

// output: localhost
$hostName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// output: http://
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://';

// return: http://localhost/myproject/
return $protocol.$hostName.$pathInfo['dirname']."/";
}
```

Then i give write the code...

```
$base = getBaseUrl();
require_once $base.'_include/db/qry.php';
require_once $base.'_include/db/functions.php';
```

Both the files `qry.php` & `functions.php` is in `http://localhost/mysite/_include/db/`

While i run the page, error shows ...

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\_include\header.php on line 9

Warning: require_once(http://localhost/mysite/_include/db/qry.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\_include\header.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/mysite/_include/db/qry.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\_include\header.php on line 9
```

I tried by echoing the getBaseUrl() like `echo $base;` and it is showing the right path i.e. `http://localhost/mysite/`.

What should I do ?

Comment: Goto `http://localhost/mysite/_include/db/qry.php` in your browser. Check whether the `404` error comes?

Comment: files are included by using paths, not URLs

Comment: shouldnt it be the path(like C:/www/abc.php) instead of the URL...require accepts paths

Comment: @Ranjith No `404 error` are comming

Comment: Fine. Try the suggested answer of @xdazz. Show of project folder structure.

Answer (score 14):

you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: This is not consistent across different server as it's coming from server's configuration file.

Answer (score 12):

You should just use the absolute path on the server instead of url.

You could get the base path by using `__DIR__`.

For example:

```
// just example, change to fit your real path.
$base = __DIR__ . '/../';

require_once $base.'_include/db/qry.php';
require_once $base.'_include/db/functions.php';
```

Comment: If the file is in `_include/db/folder1/` then what should be the `$base` ?

Comment: I have tried your instruction. I am getting the path like `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\_include/../` and my site is opening perfectly. Will it work in my web hosting ?